# I got no output using echo $SLURM_NTASKS

Tags: linux, hpc, slurm

I create this batch file myfirst_slurm_job.sh that contain the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --output="slurm1.txt"
cd $HOME/..
echo $PWD
echo $SLURMD_NODENAME
echo $SLURM_NTASKS
```

and then I run this command line:

```
sbatch myfirst_slurm_job.sh
```

note: it's my first post

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `--ntasks`/`-n` flag;

```
#SBATCH -n 1
```

else SLURM won't bother to define this variable for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if I don't specify --ntasks flag, how can I get the number of tasks this job is using ?

Comment: If you don't request a number of tasks, then they are technically not defined for the batch step. number of tasks isn't the the same as number of cores. If you care about tasks, then request tasks.

Comment: I did and still `echo $SLURM_NTASKS` prints nothing.